# SQL Query very slow with JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query like this

```
SELECT
    UserId, UserData 
FROM
    users
WHERE 
    JSON_VALUE(UserData, '$.FirstName') LIKE '%test%' 
    OR JSON_VALUE(UserData, '$.LastName') LIKE '%test%' 
    OR JSON_VALUE(UserData, '$.Mail') LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY 
    Id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

I have approx. 80k entries in the table.

Here's the issue: if the search term (in this case "test") is 1 or 2 characters long, the query takes 15 ms.

If the term has 3 or more characters, the time it takes gets up to 1500 ms.

Can someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: If the search term is two characters long, do you by any chance have many more matches? The engine only needs to return 50 rows, so with only two characters to match those 50 rows will be found sooner than if few or no rows match. The worst case for this query is when no rows match and all of them have to be enumerated in search of the 50 results that will never come. Not only does each row have to have its JSON parsed (three times), you then also perform a free-text search, so this operation can't be effectively sped up by indexing (although you could index the JSON as computed columns).

Comment: What is the performance like with `OPENJSON` instead? At least then the JSON will only be parsed once.

Comment: If you need to access json values freequently then it would be better to expose this values as computed persisted columns and create indexes on it. If you can modify a table ofcourse

Comment: @JeroenMostert you were right, I didnt realize that it stops searching after finding 50 entries
I just added to every column an index and changed the query to 3 individual selects with "union" and now it is about 25% faster